# C++ wrapper for PKCS#11 library DLL for Windows

Tags: c++, cryptography, pkcs#11

I'm trying to access a PKCS11 cryptographic token with C++ in Windows. What's the solution for connect the PKCS#11 library DLL in C++?

Comment: Does the token work as a Cryptographic Service Provider https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380245(v=vs.85).aspx ?

Comment: Then you will need the manufactures header file(s) and documentation (an import library would also be nice).  Use the import library (or LoadLibrary and GetProcAddress) and read the docs.  What have you tried so far?  PKCS#11 is a cryptographic specification not a detailed API spec so different manufactures have different calls.  If the token is designed to work with MS Windows I would be surprised that that it is not a CSP as above.